# Тонкая настройка LiveReload под sublime Text3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Нужно, чтобы LiveReload отслеживал определенные типы файлов, а не все.
Сейчас в настройках пользователя такой код:

```
{
  "enabled_plugins": [
      "SimpleReloadPlugin",
      "SimpleRefresh"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Одним из решений может быть выкинуть **сервер** LiveReload, который поддерживает пакет для Sublime Text. **Это не единственная реализация LiveReload-сервера.**

**[Есть также `guard-livereload`](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload)**: плагин для системы Guard для выполнения действий при изменении файлов. Он написан на Ruby и потому для работы требует установленного Ruby. Порядок установки минимально отличается от других плагинов для Guard, [вроде `guard-haml`, об установке и запуске которого я уже писал ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540214/181100).

В `Guardfile` можно задать шаблоны путей, изменение файлов по которым даст сигнал клиенту LiveReload для обновления. В README есть пример:

```rb
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
end
```

Код выше, разумеется, на Ruby. Каждая строчка `watch` добавляет на отслеживание пути, подходящие под регулярное выражение, относительно корня проекта (рабочей директории, где запущен `guard`). Регулярка записывается `/так/`, `%r{так}`, или другими способами. Само выражение можно проверить [на Rubular](http://rubular.com/) или просто в Interactive Ruby (IRB).

Guard можно загрузить и другими задачами, связанными с реакцией на изменение файлов.
**[См. список плагинов Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guard-Plugins).**

Answer (score 2):

Так как у "LiveReload" нет такой опции, которая могла бы решить мою проблему, я обратился за помощью к другим инструментам. Конкретно "Browsersync". Считаю хорошей альтернативой. Исполняет самую главную функцию "LiveReload", но дополняет её многими полезными инструментами и позволяет действительно тонкую настройку.

А самое главное преимущество перед тем же "LiveReload" - это возможность синхронизации на разных устройствах в одной сети (ноут, смартфон, ПК и тд.).

Так что хоть ответ выше напрямую связан с темой моего вопроса - я решил свою проблему другим методом, **который решил не саму суть вопроса, но поставленную задачу - тонкая настройка при автообновлении!**

1. Удалил плагин LiveReload;
2. Установил Node.js;
3. Поставил Browsersync (npm install -g browser-sync);

Comment: В "Sublime Text Power User" пишут, что в LiveReload тоже возможна синхронизация на разных устройствах. Только у меня мозгов не хватает, как её осуществить, см. мой вопрос на английском Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38650669/5951529 . Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть браузер для вебдевелоперов [Blisk](https://blisk.io/) на основе Chromium, умеет мониторить директории на изменения в файлах.