# Можно ли преобразовать haml в html в том же файле (как в случае с Emmet)?

Tags: html, haml

Мне нужно, чтобы в процессе редактирования html-кода в html/php файле можно было писать haml-код и при нажатии на некоторую клавишу, haml преобразовывался в html.
Подобным образом работает Emmet.

Comment: Уточните редактор или среду разработки.

Comment: Sublime Text 3, но если эта возможность есть для других редакторов, было бы тоже интересно узнать

Answer (score 1):

#### Можно и не требовать этого от самого редактора

Можно использовать **непосредственно HAML** и писать разметку на нём, генерируя HTML автоматически. Поддержка редакторов для этого не нужна, нужен только достаточно свежий Ruby (2.2+) с гемом `bundler` (`gem install bundler` его установит при наличии RubyGems) на машине.

На Ruby это сделать достаточно легко с помощью ["следилки" `guard-haml`](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml).

- Делаем в папке проекта вот такой `Gemfile`:

  ```ruby
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'guard-haml'
  ```
- Делаем `bundle install`, чтобы оно установилось и сгенерило `Gemfile.lock`
- Делаем `guard init`, чтобы сгенерился `Guardfile`, в котором будут определяться правила для слежения за файлами и их перегенерации, изначально он обнаружит `guard-haml` и сделает для него правило (справочный комментарий сверху опущен):

  ```ruby
  guard :haml do
    watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)$/) # Это регулярка для путей к исходным файлам
  end
  ```

  Можно добавить в правило папку "исходных файлов" и "результата", чтобы они не были в одной куче:

  ```ruby
  guard :haml, input: 'src', output: 'public' do
    watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)$/)
  end
  ```
- Создаём где-то в папке с исходниками (или текущей) любой файл вида `*.html.haml`, сохраняем, и вуаля, в папке с результатом (или текущей) появляется соответствующий `*.html`.
- Если надо выйти из Guard, можно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> или выполнить в его консоли `exit`.